# URL issue in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

i wanted to give a link at html page to download. as i am getting `URI` via ajax function and trying to add in `href` link

e.g. getinng response via ajax  `responseText = \dir\user\file.zip`

```
 var link = "<a href=" + '"' + "http://localhost:8080/myProject/" +ajaxRequest.responseText + '"' + ">Download</a>";

$("#download-lin").html(link);  // not working as download link
```

now i am adding the above link as html in a `div` but it's not working as download link. please correct me if possible.

Comment: I doubt `http://localhost:8080/myProject/\dir\user\file.zip` is a valid URL.

Comment: `dir\user\file.zip ` this isn't working, you are right. so how can i change the `\` to `/` in js fn().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var URL = ajaxRequest.responseText.replace('\\', '/').substr(1);
var link = '<a href="http://localhost:8080/myProject/' + URL + '">Download</a>';

$("#download-lin").html(link);
```

Though I would suggest you fix this serverside, not clientside.

Comment: Lol, not problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `append()` function. eg: `$("#mydiv").append(link);`